# using OBD II how can i detect an accident with airbag

Tags: obd-ii, supplemental-restraint-system

i need help with c++ program, if either the airbag is triggered or the deceleration detected is greater than 5 Gs, we consider that an accident occurred. The vehicle decides to ask  nearby by sendig SMS.

Comment: What exactly is your question ... Do you need the OBDII output, or what?

Comment: Do you know the proper PID's? What are you struggling with exactly?

Comment: i need th OBD2 output that show airbag triggred

Comment: What car is it? Airbag PID's aren't standard in the OBD2 protocol, so you're going to have to find out from the manufacturer.

Comment: I want to make a program with c + + that contains a loop testing airbag and works as follows: "if either the airbag is triggered or the deceleration detected is greater than 5 Gs, we consider that an accident occurred". my problem is, how can i know if the airbag is triggered or no, then we can test with OBD2 or with other method??
my experience with peugeot vehicle 407.

Comment: Is your loop to test and display (or however you are getting the information out) during an event, or check to see if these parameters have ever happened (after an event)? Are you trying to do something like *Onstar* where a signal is sent out as the event occurs? I don't have answers to any of this, but hopefully helping you flesh out your question a little better.

Comment: what is the actuator that triggers airbag??

Comment: @Paulster. The overarching problem is that airbag sensors aren't standard OBD PID's and manufacturers are very stingy about sharing the info on their custom implementations. E.g. some services charge $4000(no typo) per year for workshops to gain access to this information. So obviously they don't want people getting their hands on this for free.

Comment: @JuannStrauss ... aren't the SRS and ABS systems separate from the OBDII system? I mean, you read them through the ALDL plug, but I thought they were read off of different pins.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming

Comment: @GabrielMongeon ... there has been [other questions](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/8608/reading-can-messages-through-uart-to-obd-ii-board-and-matlab-toolbox) very similar to this which was answered.

Answer (score 1):

This will be specific to each vehicle Manufacturer and some specific to make and model. It's not covered in OBD-II and is propitiatory for each manufacturer. You might be able to detect by monitoring the CAN buss but again it will be specific to each manufacturer. You may be better off using your own G-force sensor to determine if there has been an accident, although you want the threshold to be much lower than 5 G's. The sensor type varies but all but rollover sensors measure G-force, and require two separate sensors to close at the same time, sometimes called an arming and discriminating sensor.